# MySQL Problem with Umlauts

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, diacritics

i have a big problem with umlauts.
I have a normal registration Form. And when i click on Submit, i send the data via jQuery Ajax to a php Script.
This Script puts everything in my database.

The Database Collation is utf8_general_ci but the umlauts are displayed like crap :D
When i submit a new User to that database in the backend, where only php plays it works with umlauts.

Where is my fault?
Can´t figure it out.

Thanks :)

Comment: @Tyler: I seriously doubt Jings meant excrement. A smiley rendered with the wrong character encoding might look like this: â�ş (copied and pasted from Aptana, which has a char encoding problem). It definitely looks like crap.

Comment: @mingos: I hardly think an accurate description of erroneous output is too much to ask for. Yes, it likely is an encoding issue, but who really knows when OP doesn't give nessesary info.

Comment: Linguistic laziness on the OP's part is a fact, I can't argue with that. But let's not push this too far: "like crap" is a very common manner of describing something as "bad, erroneous", for me it's as precise as it gets when dealing with mangled non-ascii character output (with which I deal often, as my language has a myriad of such characters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you're using UTF-8 everywhere in that chain. Your page needs to be encoded in UTF-8, so that the browser submits the user-data correctly. Check the `Content-Type` header of the request. Your webserver should deliver the MIME-type with `; encoding=UTF-8`.